# JMeter BeanShell Assertion: Getting error when convert String to Long

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell

Have a need to change the value from String to Long in BeanShell Assertion to do verification.

**First Apporach**

```
long balance_after_credit = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf("${balance_after_credit_from_db}"));
```

**Second Approach**

```
long balance_after_credit = Long.parseLong(vars.get("balance_after_credit_from_db"));
```

For instance, consider am getting a value as '743432545' for the variable `balance_after_credit_from_db.`

**Error**

```
org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``long token_balance_after_credit = Long.parseLong(vars.get("token_balance_after_c . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation Long.parseLong
```

Weird thing is sometimes, I didn't get errors and the script is getting passed.
Can anyone please point out where am doing a mistake. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Inlining JMeter variables into code-based scripts is not something recommended so go for 2nd approach.
2. How do you know that **exactly** String is being returned from the database all the time? It easily can be any other object type, in fact any of described in the [Mapping SQL and Java Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html) article. The way more safe approach will be something like:

   ```
   if (vars.getObject("balance_after_credit_from_db") instanceof String) {
       long balance_after_credit = Long.parseLong(vars.get("balance_after_credit_from_db"));
   } 
   else {
       log.error("Unexpected \balance_after_credit_from_db\" variable type");
       log.error("Expected: String, Actual: " + vars.getObject("balance_after_credit_from_db").getClass().getName());
       throw new Exception("Unexpected variable type");
   }
   ```

   So in case of non-String JDBC query result you will be able to see the relevant message in *jmeter.log* file

   [image: JMeter variable type]

See [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) article for more information on working with the entities coming from databases in JMeter tests

Answer (score 0):

The second option

```
long balance_after_credit = Long.parseLong(vars.get("balance_after_credit_from_db"));
```

should work, provided you have a valid numeric variable value. For instance try to run something like this:

```
vars.put("x", "743432545");
long balance_after_credit = Long.parseLong(vars.get("x"));
```

It won't return any exception.
The problem is when the variable is not defined, has empty or non-numeric value. Then `Long.parseLong` will throw a `NumberFormatException`, which you shold catch and make use of (treat it as assertion failure):

```
String rawValue = vars.get("balance_after_credit_from_db");

long balance_after_credit = Long.MAX_VALUE; // initialize with some unrealistic value

try {
    balance_after_credit = Long.parseLong(rawValue);
}
catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    Failure = true;
    FailureMessage = "Variable does not contain a valid long. It was " + rawValue + " instead";
}
```